# How to call stored procedure inside function

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a function that would check two tables, first check would check a unique ID if it's good, it will select these values.

```
ELSE
    EXEC [StoredProcedure]
```

and check UNIQUE ID

```
CREATE FUNCTION [Test].[TId]
    (@ID UNIQUE IDENTIFIER)
AS
BEGIN   
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [UID] WHERE [ID] = @ID)
        SELECT
            [ID],
        FROM 
            [Test].[UID]
        WHERE 
            [ID] = @ID
    )
    ELSE 
        EXEC [Test].[StoredProcedure]
```

Comment: Plain and simple...this is not possible.

Comment: Can you elaborate, please? should I create a stored procedure then?

Comment: Functions cannot `EXEC`, @duckGame . The above logic seems like it should be in another procedure. It certainly shouldn't be a function, as it's attempting to be a multi-line table type, and those perform *terribly*.

Comment: Well your function code is incomplete and broken currently because there is no return type stated. But it also seems like you are potentially going to return different result sets which could very likely even return different columns. A stored procedure might be a better option but without any knowledge of what you are trying to do it is impossible to say.

Comment: I also notice you are assigning values to your inbound parameters. That is how you can make parameters optional in a stored procedure. But parameters in a function are not optional, they all must be provided every time (even if they are NULL).

Comment: What does the procedure do?